# React: setState inside a promise does not change the state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I have the following code:

```
function App() {

 const [appData, setAppData] = useState(initialAppDataValue);
const [test, setTest] = useState("");

// outside useEffect
if(!DataProviderService.isInitialized){
    fetchData();
}

// inside useEffect
/*useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, []);*/

function fetchData(){
    DataProviderService.getAppData().then((data) => {
        setAppData(data);
        setTest("abc");
    });
}

return (<div>something...</div>);
}
```

If I call 'fetchData' outside useEffect the update of the state is not working BUT if I do it inside useEffect it works fine.

My question is why?
Outside of useEffect I update the state and then I see that re-render is called but the value doesn't contain the new value. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

In this code, fetchData is called when component is rendering.
When first rendering, DataProviderService is not initialized and fetchData is not called.
After that, no states or props are changed, and the component is not re-rendered again and fetchData is not called.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the data you want to display is data you want to fetch on mount and not change during the users interactions (at least as far as this component is aware). So as far as I can tell the desired behaviour is:

1. **Component Mounts**
2. **Data is fetched**
3. **State changes to reflect the data returned**
4. **State stays here as long as the component is mounted**

If your page was interactive and triggered state changes/re-renders after the initial mount, then the fetch request would work with the state changes. However this would have undesired consequences since it would be called on every re-render, but this wouldn't be desirable either!

Calling a fetch request outside of a useEffect in this manner is going rogue and ignoring the react lifecycle. Remember everytime a component re-renders and the JSX is compiled it will go over your component line by line and execute every function you've told it to execute. In this instance the fetch request will exist in a vacum and be called each re-render without a thought or care about what the current or previous state was causing the infinite re-render loop of doom.

The useEffect will run after the component has initially rendered and thus be aware of the initial state and how it relates to the elements in the component. This will not only lead to your desired outcome, where the fetch request will be called on the initial mounting, but you can use the dependency array to tell react "render this on mount and then not again" or "render this when x, y or z state changes or functions are called"

TLDR: Because I am more of a visual person I've put together a [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLg2S.png) explaining what's going on with the lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

*When you call fetchData outside the useEffect, it runs immediately when the component is rendered. The DataProviderService.getAppData().then(...) part is asynchronous which means that it doesn't wait for the result before moving on to the next lines of code and starts the process but doesn't wait. setAppData and setTest are functions that update the component's state. When the state is updated, it triggers a re-render of the component. As we know the promise is asynchronous, the state updates might not have been completed by the time the re-render occurs. This can lead to a situation where the component re-renders with the old state values.

When you put fetchData inside the useEffect with an empty [], it ensures that fetchData is only executed once when the component is first displayed.The DataProviderService.getAppData().then(...) part is doing some work, and it takes time to finish. But now, because fetchData is inside useEffect, it doesn't run immediately when the component renders.The useEffect captures the first time the component is shown on the screen. It waits for the asynchronous work (DataProviderService.getAppData().then(...)) to complete before moving on.After the asynchronous work is done, the state is updated using setAppData and setTest. This triggers a re-render, but now the re-render happens after the asynchronous task is finished. So, when the component re-renders, it shows the updated and correct information.*